# ios phonegap dialog not visible

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am facing a weird problem ever since I rebuilt the app a week back. When the app loads, its stuck at PhoneGap splash logo (which doesn't exist in the app at all). If I minimise the app and restore it, I can see location permissions popup (I am using location services, ideally it should be visible as modal in the app, not hidden)

Further into the app, when the user selects camera or gallery, the same thing happens. I have to minimise and restore app to see the screen.

I tried downgrading PhoneGap-CLI (from 6.4.0 to 6.30). I created a fresh app and reinstalled the plugin/platform etc & copied the www folder. But the issue is still same.

PS: I am not locking the plugins to any specific version

Answer (score 0):

the real reason being deviceready wasn't getting fired. What I had to do was add

gap://ready in the content-security-policy meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
```

thanks